# Can I download a picture from my internal memory in android-studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an android application... I would like to know if I can do this:

When I press the bottom button which is in the menu, this one download the drawable folder without connecting on internet to download it. Can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy pictures from your drawable folder ?

Comment: you can load pictures from internal memory into your activity. BUT show us what you have tried yet (some code).

Comment: As you can see in the image ( url ) . I would like that If I press the button download the image will be downloaded.In this case, it is a restaurant's menu. It is a png format, which is stored in app/src/main/res/drawable. I haven`t tried any code yet. I`ve searched in google, but the only one that I find is the way to upload it to a server and download it in order to have internet connection . My question is ... Can I do that? 
I mean, when you install the app in your phone and you press the button, the image (restaurant's menu) is DOWNLOADED, without having internet connection .

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gyax0br30k9xdi/Captura.PNG?dl=0